# fox pro ODBC : Feature is not available when inserting data

Tags: php, odbc, foxpro

I have a dbfcdx file indexed using xharbour DBFCDX RDD set using the RDDSetDefault("DBFCDX") function.

I can read and write to the file with a PHP\ODBC application using the Microsoft Visual FoxPro ODBC Driver version 6.01.8629.01 but when i try to do an insert on the database the ODBC driver return this error:

[Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]Feature is not available.

This error is truly random, for many days everything works fine and suddenly the problem arises and than it disappears without doing anything  after few hours to reappear again few weeks later and so on.

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Posting the actual insert command would help.

Comment: the query is simple   INSERT INTO SRISP (SOC,COD,TIPOC,DATAI,ORAI,UTE) VALUES ([TLF],[00012],[DOC],DATE(),TIME(),[OPERATOR1])